# Who canceled my Task?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

My C# Task is getting canceled, but not by me. I don't get a stacktrace and I can't figure out where the problem occurs.

My task invocation looks like this:

```
var t = Task<Boolean>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Boolean bOk = DoSomthingImportant();
        return bOk;
    }, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
    .ContinueWith<Boolean>((theTask) =>
    {
        var reason = theTask.IsCanceled ? "it was canceled" : "it faulted";
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: Task ended because " + reason + ".");
        ... log the exception to one of my objects...
        return false;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

I want the continuation task to run if the task faulted or was canceled, but not if it ran okay.
The continuation is never executed.

Later on my program catches an AggregateException which is wrapping a TaskCanceledException.

My other major interaction with my tasks is to call WaitAny(taskArray, timeout) until I have no more tasks to start, then call WaitAll with no timeout until the last task is done.

Could WaitAny with a timeout cause a cancellation? Why didn't my continuation get called?

This is only my second brush with the Task library, so I am clueless.

UPDATE:

I found this SO question: How to propagate a Task's Canceled status to a continuation task.
One error in my code above (but not the cause of the Cancelation) is that I assumed that the Continuation tasks status was the same as the original task's status. In fact you have to do some work to get the one from the other, as the other post describes.

UPDATE 2:

Brian: Thanks for the documentaion reference. I had searched high and low for alternate causes of a Task being canceled, but missed these words:

> "If you are waiting on a Task that transitions to the Canceled state,
>   a Task (wrapped in an AggregateException) is manufactured and thrown.
>   Note that this exception indicates successful cancellation instead of
>   a faulty situation. Therefore, the Task's Exception property returns
>   null."

Comment: Don't know what your issue is but you might not know you don't need `<Boolean>` both when accessing `Task.Factory` (it's defined on `Task`) and when calling `ContinueWith` (it will be inferred based on what you return). Of course it doesn't help the error, just makes the syntax shorter.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Dan. I like concise code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're waiting on the continuation and since the original task ran to completion the continuation task was cancelled. This behavior is covered in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).

Comment: Are you serious? That is insane. Logically consistent, but insane. I will investigate.

Comment: In your example `t` points to the continuation. The only reference to the original task is `theTask`. What state would you expect the continuation to have at this point?

Comment: @PaulChernoch do you suggest it is insane API design? It is actually very sound design because it allows you to treat the task and its continuation differently. They are separate tasks. The fact that you chain-invoked methods on them is not a fact that the TPL can (magically) know and react to.

Comment: If you are right, and I captured the correct task to Wait on, do I have to do anything to keep the Continuation task from throwing an exception if it gets canceled because it is unneeded? How and where do I detect that case?

Comment: @usr: I was using insane in a loose sense. The "logically consistent" part of my comment means that it makes sense when viewed the way the designers intended it, but it is insane because that conception was very different from what I thought it was doing, and sanity means "thinking the way I do". ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. The bottom-line is that if you `Wait` on a cancelled task, you trigger the exception. While this may be confusing, allowing a cancelled task to be awaited would be more confusing as you wouldn't be able to tell if it ran to completion or was cancelled.

Comment: Note: The ContinueWith's task was canceled on success of the original task only because it was passed the argument "TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion", without passing this option the ContinueWith task is not canceled on success of the original task.