# Task gets canceled if i use ContinueWith

Tags: c#

The following works just fine

```
 var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
 Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

However when I use continue with instead of the above as the following

```
using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
    //...
    client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(responseTask => {
        if (responseTask.IsFaulted) {
            Console.WriteLine(responseTask.Exception.Message);
        } 
        else 
            if (responseTask.IsCanceled) {
                Console.WriteLine("responseTask was canceld");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result.StatusCode);
            }
    });
}
```

`responseTask.IsCanceled` is always true even though I did not cancel the task, can someone please explain this behavior, I myself did not cancel the task, and if something else cancelled it I thought the first snipped wouldn't work either but it does, am I doing anything wrong in the second snippet?

Comment: The `Task` you are continuing from is created by `client`. What type is `client`? It is probably cancelling the task.

Comment: @Gusdor client is of type `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, but if it was canceling it why does the first sniped work?

Comment: Do you have a `using` statement wrapped around the client?

Comment: @Gusdor yes!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @that was the problem, I removed it and it works, please post an answer

Comment: No need, there is already an answer for this ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631349/why-is-the-original-task-canceled-when-it-continuewith-something-else?rq=1

Comment: For the record, you really should dispose of the `HttpClient` but `using` may not be the best method. I would always recommend using `await` at some point.